# Каким образом приложение на С# для автотестов (Selenium) развернуть в интернете?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Использую C#, Selenium.Webdriver, фреймворк Atata, PhantomJS.

Написал много автотестов (библиотека), теперь стоит вопрос, как из этого сделать работающее приложение: должно размещаться в интернете, и периодически или по команде тестировать сайты клиентов.

Какой тип проекта для этого использовать? WebApi, или Asp.Net MVC, или что-то иное? Что предпочесть, чем еще улучшить проект?

И какие у решения делать все на C# есть недостатки, слабые стороны, особеннь в плане дальнейшего развития? Не стоит ли предпочесть решение на Python?

Comment: У Вас уже имеется сервер на котором Вы планируете разместить своё будущее приложение? Сколько клиентов планируете обслуживать одновременно? Рассматриваются ли платные варианты или только бесплатные?

Comment: нет, сервера пока нет, 
кол-во клиентов пока неизвестно - пока это находится в стадии изучения и тестирования,
в перспективе платные возможны, но стартовать с бесплатных.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько вам это поможет, расскажу как с этой задачей справился я, это как один из вариантов.
**Вариант №1**

Есть 3 больших набора автотестов, каждый набор это отдельное Windows-приложение(консольное, .exe)
Админ выделил мне виртуальную машину внутри нашей сети, на которой размещены данные наборы тестов.
Я написал приложение-чекер(агент), который проверяет БД на наличие новых задач. Задачи в БД создаются через веб-интерфейс. Агент находит задачи необходимые для запуска и запускает конкретное приложение(автотест).

Суть в том, что агент висит на той же машине, где лежат тесты и просто делает

```
Process.Start("AutotestName.exe");
```

После завершения автотест отправляет на E-mail отчет в формате HTML

Так же в веб-интерфейсе можно настроить для каждого теста расписание на запуск, поэтому автотесты у нас гоняются ночью =)

**Вариант №2**

Использовать TeamCity для запуска тестов.
Например у меня на прошлой работе все автотесты представлялись в виде `.dll` с использованием `NUnit`.
В *TeamCity* был настроен билд и запуск автотеста, запуск автотестов по кнопке, просмотр результатов там же в виде Passed/Failed.
Но для *TeamCity* так же должен быть установлен агент на билд-машине